# Are there complex Bernoulli numbers?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, divergent-series

I am aware of the  [generalized Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generalized_Bernoulli_numbers), but these are not what I'm looking for. I was wondering if there exists such a thing as fractional, real or even complex Bernoulli numbers ( $B_z$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$).

My motivation comes from the [Ramanujan Summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation), as the Bernoulli numbers are involved in it. I was hoping that, if the Bernoulli numbers could be extendend, so could perhaps the Ramanujan Summation, allowing it to assign a sum to a wider class of divergent series.

Comment: How would writing down fractional, real, or complex Bernoulli numbers help you extend Ramanujan summation?

Comment: @Qiaochu The Bernoulli numbers are involved in the Ramanujan summation function. I suppose that I'm hoping that if every component of the Ramanujan summation formula could be extended to higher argument analogous (So this includes replacing the $(k+1)!$ term by $\Gamma(z)$), an extension of Ramanujan summation could be made possible. I'm not really sure the extension of functions to larger sets of arguments works like that, though.

Comment: @Qiaochu I guess more work needs to be done to extend Ramanujan summation. For example, I think you also need to know how to differentiate some function fractionally (see the $f^{k}(n)$ term). I should not that the motivation not only stems from extending the Ramanujan summation, but I think a generalization of Bernoulli numbers is also interesting on its own right.

Comment: Do you think there is a chance that Ramanujan summation could be extended by means of some ideas that are loosely based on the things I just said in the comments?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ramanujan himself gave a definition of Bernoulli numbers for a complex index - see Ramanujan's Notebooks - Part 1 by Bruce C. Berndt, [Chapter 5 equation (25.1)](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=liTRR8UnTq4C&pg=PA125) with further results in [Chapter 7](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=liTRR8UnTq4C&pg=PA150).

---

**Added by J. M.:**

Ramanujan's definition of the Bernoulli numbers, as given in Berndt's book, is

$$B_s^\ast=\frac{2\Gamma(s+1)}{(2\pi)^s}\zeta(s)$$

Comment: This is a nice precise answer, thanks!